# Connecting postgresql to symfony2 project

Tags: php, database, postgresql, symfony

I have created a symfony2 project. I have installed Postgresql. Do I have to create a new database within pgadmin tool, pick up data (db name,db user,db pw) and then enter it inside parametres.yml file of my symfony project? 
This is my parametres.yml file

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_pgsql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 5432
database_name: test_db
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: 98c7cab866879d9250d316445c6d136c922a6b6f
```

I've tried my very best to find a 'dummy tutorial' to help me from scratch, since this is my first time connecting a database to a project.
What I have found:

By entering a command

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

I am supposed to create a database with the parametres given in the parametres.yml file. When I run the command, I get these exceptions

http://prntscr.com/8kbclu

which means server has gone out and closed the connection.

My full question is how to connect postgresql database to a symfony project from scratch?

Comment: Shouldn't the db driver be `pdo_pgsql`?

Comment: It should, I forgot to mention I edited the parametres.yml file and db driver is indeed  
      pdo_pgsql

Comment: Instead of linking a screenshot to your code, would you edit with a copy/pasted snippet?

Comment: I removed the link and added a snippet.